# Mozilla : I want to pop up my own dialog on save button of File Download Dilaog

Tags: visual-c++

Hi I want to pop up my own dialog on save button of File Download Dilaog in Mozilla. Can you suugest me how it is possible. I am working for local application not for the web application.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a java applet that manages your file download.

Comment: actually i want to manage save option of dialog. i want to pop up my own dialog to save the files. Like when user click on save option my own dialog should appear that manage functionality.

Comment: I think you can do that emebebing it as an icon or a button. 

For example on Facebook when you upload an image you get a personalized browser in java applet. You should be able of doing the same for downloading.